# C++ WINAPI - Draw ListView without borders

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm having a little trouble.

For parent window I used dimensions 920x570.
For ListView 900x500.

Viewing at this dimensions, one would say there are quite some borders, however it is not like that in reality. If I use exactly the same dimensions I get quite a big part of ListView cuted off.
Well I could try to find exact values which will give me "borderless" ListView, but even when I do so thing is slightly different in Windows XP (we are talking about 5-10 pixels).

Is there right way to draw ListView "borderless" natively to work on all platforms?

They say picture is worth a thousands of words... so here it goes

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X7IQk.png)

Comment: Not tried it, but perhaps remove the border-rendering bits (such as WS_BORDER) from the style and extended style masks used for child-creation? Just a thought. Been awhile since I did win32 comnctrl stuff. There may be extras such as WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, WS_EX_STATICEDGE, and WS_EX_WINDOWEDGE, etc... that I'm missing.

Comment: Tried modifying all styles you have mentioned on both parent and child window. None of them worked.

Comment: Use AdjustWindowRectEx() to get the window size you need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to distinguish between window size and client size. If your parent window is 920x570, then these are its outer dimensions. Client area is smaller and that's what you need to set your listview's dimension to to make it fit nicely in the entire area.

Have a look at [GetClientRect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633503%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function. You need to set ListView's dimensions to those you get using this funcion.

**EDIT**

Your code could look as follows

```
HWND outerWnd = CreateWindowEx(...);
RECT clientRect;
GetClientRect(outerWnd, &clientRect);
HWND listView = CreateWindowEx(..., WC_LISTVIEW, "", WS_CHILD|..., 0, 0, clientRect.right, clientRect.bottom, outerWnd, NULL, hInstance, NULL);
```

With `GetClientRect`, right and bottom members of RECT struct are width and height of the window, respectively.